# Are all martingales uniformly integrable

Tags: martingales, uniform-integrability

There is this problem on my sheet:

Let $X = (X)_{n≥0}$ be a martingale and $T$ be a finite stopping time. Suppose $X_T$ is integrable. Show that $$E [X_T] = E [X_0]$$ if and only if
$$\lim_{n→∞} E[X_n : T > n] = 0$$

I have a proof of this which boils down to using DCT and the fact the $X_{T ∧n}$ tends to $X_T$ as $n → ∞$

However, we have that a consequence from Doob's optional stopping Theorem that if $S,T$ are $2$ bounded stopping times, then $E[X_S]=E[X_T]$.

Doesn't this imply that $\lim_{n→∞} E[X_n : T > n] = 0$ for every martingale which is basically uniform integrability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it implies that, because you're given just that $T$ is a *finite* stopping time, not that $T$ is a *bounded* stopping time.

If $T$ is a bounded stopping time then for large enough $n$ the event $T>n$ is empty. I have no idea what the definition of $E[X:\emptyset]$ might be.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks a lot!